# Ruby expect sft script runs from command line, fails to log in from cron

Tags: ruby, cron, expect

I have a ruby program that uses expect to perform a password-login sftp session.

When I run the program from the command line, it works, but when I let cron run it, the remote server never acknowledges that the program has sent the password.

A shell-based expect script was written by somebody else, which works from cron

Is this problem related to ptys?  Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Proper permissions and environment variables are both problems when running from cron. Confirm that the correct user is running the session, and that the environment variables needed have been set.

Comment: I can confirm that it is the proper user. I am unaware of which env variables you mean.  I'm concerned that it has something to do with an extra pty that gets used strictly for passwords. And that the ruby expect isn't interacting with the prompt from the new pty correctly.